# rsyslog config forward all messages but not kern facility

Tags: rsyslog

I want to forward all messages to a remote syslog server,
but only not the kern facility.
Is that possible?

I read the manpage and find only filter for whitelist, not for blacklist.

many thanks
Karsten

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That can be achieved quite easily, but without telling me what version you are using, or which syntax you want to work with (there are 3 types in rsyslog, rainerscript being the newest). Generally, I would say it would be easiest to do this with the traditional rsyslog config syntax, and you could do it with something like:

```
*.*;auth,authpriv.none @@rsyslog;RFC3164fmt
```

Here we are saying:

```
*.*                    Send everything
auth,authpriv.none     Except auth and authpriv
@@rsyslog              send to host "rsyslog" with TCP (defined by using@@, using @ would send via UDP)
RFC3164fmt             Send using the RFC3164fmt format template
```